# inserting an html table into an already present html file with placeholders

Tags: html, css

i am trying to insert a table with predefined html and css such as the following:

```html
<style>table, th, td {
padding: 2px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 630px;
table-layout: fixed;
}
</style>

<table style="margin: 3pxborder: 5px solid black" >
<tr style="background-color: #aeaeae" >
<th>&nbsp</th>

  <th colspan=1 style="color: white" >header1</th>
  <th colspan=1 style="color: white" >header2</th>
</tr>


<tr style="background-color: white;table-layout: fixed" >
  
    <td style="padding: 1rem" >Value1</td>
    <td style="padding: 1rem" >11</td>
    <td style="padding: 1rem" >12</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: white;table-layout: fixed" >
  
    <td style="padding: 1rem" >Value2</td>
    <td style="padding: 1rem" >21</td>
    <td style="padding: 1rem" >22</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

into an already present html file with placeholders where the table values would go. I tried inserting the css part into the section where the css is defined, but it seems that it is not being recognized the way it is if the abovementioned table is pasted into a single file. The file with the placeholders is split into shared and inline css, which section would the css belonging to the table be assigned to?

Comment: you should show how are you inserting the table in the eixisting code

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue here with CSS specificity, but based on what you have shown so far, it is impossible to tell at which point. Please provide a proper [mre] of the actual problem, and a detailed explanation of what exactly is wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Or can you please elaborate what you want to ask.

```html
    <style>
table, th, td {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 630px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    }
     table{ margin: 3px; border: 5px solid black; }
    
      table tr.bg_aeaea th{ color: white; }
      table tr.bg_aeaea{ background-color: #aeaeae; }
      table tr.valued{ .background-color: white; table-layout: fixed; }
    table tr.valued td{ padding: 1rem;}

     
    </style>

    <table>
    <tr class="bg_aeaea">
    <th>&nbsp</th>
      <th colspan=1>header1</th>
      <th colspan=1 >header2</th>
    </tr>


    <tr class="valued" >
      
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="valued" >
      
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```